# Problemas con RDD en Spark (Scala)

Tags: scala

Buenos días, tengo un problema con el siguiente código:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

case class Navegacion(fecha_local: String, idusuario: String, ip: String, pais_iso2: String, _F: String, idpageview: String,
                      dominio: String, url: String, idextension: String, extension_version: String, source: String,
                      partner: String, first: String, categoria: String, subcategoria: String, catWS: String)

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Admin")
conf.setMaster("local[1]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val file = "C:/logs.txt"

val rddFile = sc.textFile(file)
rddFile.filter(row => row != rddFile.first()) //elimino la cabecera
rddFile.foreach(println)

val rddSplit = rddFile.map(line => {
    val arr = line.split(";")
    val catWS = "lo que sea" //Esta variable la calcularé con una función y será distinta cada vez
    new Navegacion(
      arr(0).replaceAll("\"", "").toString, //fecha_local
      arr(1).toString, //idusuario
      arr(2).toString, //ip
      arr(3).toString, //pais_iso2
      arr(4).toString, //_F
      arr(5).toString, //idpageview
      arr(6).toString, //dominio
      arr(7).toString, //url
      arr(8).toString, //idextension
      arr(9).toString, //extension_version
      arr(10).toString, //source
      arr(11).toString, //partner
      arr(12).toString, //first
      arr(13).toString, //categoria
      arr(14).replaceAll("\"", "").toString,
      catWS.toString) //categoriaWS)
  })

rddSplit.foreach(println)
```

El fichero `logs.txt` tiene la siguiente información:

> fecha_local;idusuario;ip;pais_iso2;_F;idpageview;dominio;url;idextension;extension_version;source;partner;first;categoria;subcategoria
>   20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;009fe203badd9ef18ee5774183fcc1a6;sso.cmpc.com.mx;https://sso.cmpc.com.mx/SSOv2/processJespa;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;;
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;00e8c1d5a9b83d1d48c2be423d99b32a;facebook.com;https://www.facebook.com/;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       8; 95
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;00e8c1d5a9b83d1d48c2be423d99b32a;facebook.com;https://www.facebook.com/;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;39678c78aa1a570c04818e9f672375f3;mail.google.com;https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       8; 98
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;3ab94c00842c80193d9c2da3e01db9b6;google.com.mx;https://www.google.com.mx/webhp?ei=e2MUVbL-JMOmggT3qITgDw&ved=0CAQQqS4oAg;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;40f2aecb272af641e6bde1f0d7908a21;google.com.mx;https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=sillones+de+operacion&biw=1366&bih=643&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMhdqgsLzMAhVH_WMKHdedD1YQ_AUIBigB;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;43fdc4ae0aeb94c24930177e7bd4b9b5;facebook.com;https://www.facebook.com/;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       8; 95
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;43fdc4ae0aeb94c24930177e7bd4b9b5;facebook.com;https://www.facebook.com/;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;6677ad2493f3f3268e7961822d10173a;google.com.mx;https://www.google.com.mx/webhp?ei=e2MUVbL-JMOmggT3qITgDw&ved=0CAQQqS4oAg;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;7649abae513d74cd05327ca57aa31a78;google.com;https://www.google.com/a/empresascmpc.com/acs;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;7707fc1d9edd388450d926bc4b4c7405;google.com.mx;https://www.google.com.mx/webhp?ie=UTF-8&rct=j;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;7bc8b5662bd8e4c6a2054d6109f95f51;google.com.mx;https://www.google.com.mx/search?rls=aso&client=gmail&q=sci+ssi.proyectos%40hotmail.com+&authuser=0&gws_rd=cr&ei=9ZInV4-2O8vpjgSqm7vQDw;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;7cb60be10047a2d14b6f6291dd8ec7d9;;;jlbdpggcodceafgpkblhoelmoankanjh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;;
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;90920eb7ffb8492b75687a456dc505c1;google.com.mx;https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=f&rct=j&url=https://es-la.facebook.com/&q=&esrc=s&ei=DqsnV_XSKcbwjgT-wrfYAQ&usg=AFQjCNFQfedqb_gYW9wFdGVtA4-IjzGbVw;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;a3e58156e1ebc1688bef133d9cfaed2d;google.com.mx;https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=sillon+operativo&biw=1366&bih=643&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz6JXjsLzMAhVK7mMKHR8WACwQ_AUIBigB;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;ab0c12c3c640e5066ff827abf79c1d4b;thenexttask.com;http://www.thenexttask.com/?utm_source=sf-home;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;;
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;b40825c5916911ff23562f0cf4e29796;google.com.mx;https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=f&rct=j&url=https://es-la.facebook.com/&q=&esrc=s&ei=7MUnV5a_IqbbjgS7kquABQ&usg=AFQjCNH459aM5UmZ_IWh-zFbpddBwCXE6g;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;b84bbd8e135112e5e47bb62be5748ff5;portal.cmpc.com.mx;http://portal.cmpc.com.mx/;jlbdpggcodceafgpkblhoelmoankanjh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;;
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;c8917341ca1aff1ad129c3684de5a2c1;google.com.mx;https://www.google.com.mx/webhp?ei=e2MUVbL-JMOmggT3qITgDw&ved=0CAQQqS4oAg;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;c89b1bf3ee94205584a2d2436999764e;facebook.com;https://www.facebook.com/;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       8; 95
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;c89b1bf3ee94205584a2d2436999764e;facebook.com;https://www.facebook.com/;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;f93b51cc8dfa9f86fadda49ce0a5e848;google.com.mx;https://www.google.com.mx/webhp?ei=e2MUVbL-JMOmggT3qITgDw&ved=0CAQQqS4oAg#q=sillones+de+operacion;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000069be-2f9a-41a6-baae-730cd8780604;83.213.241.17;ES;100004945907632;00bb3b83d1f7f9a1ce6a2aa815b953b8;oi.bankia.es;https://oi.bankia.es/es/login;eikkoifbpgbfhomedpfcahpnghoencio;80;ADW|MEX_ES_00_P_Friv_IDE001_oo_oo_S_A;ADW;;
>       13; 164
>       20160502;000069be-2f9a-41a6-baae-730cd8780604;83.213.241.17;ES;100004945907632;0903a3f56aa2f062f9004d08bd0cd5fe;paisdelosjuegos.es;http://www.paisdelosjuegos.es/juegos/dinosaurio?gclid=CJ6epaqHvMwCFfEV0wodt6YH_w;eikkoifbpgbfhomedpfcahpnghoencio;80;ADW|MEX_ES_00_P_Friv_IDE001_oo_oo_S_A;ADW;;
>       28; 357
>       20160502;000069be-2f9a-41a6-baae-730cd8780604;83.213.241.17;ES;100004945907632;094f88428bacbf123840763a5240c095;facebook.com;https://www.facebook.com/;eikkoifbpgbfhomedpfcahpnghoencio;80;ADW|MEX_ES_00_P_Friv_IDE001_oo_oo_S_A;ADW;;
>       8; 95
>       20160502;000069be-2f9a-41a6-baae-730cd8780604;83.213.241.17;ES;100004945907632;094f88428bacbf123840763a5240c095;facebook.com;https://www.facebook.com/;eikkoifbpgbfhomedpfcahpnghoencio;80;ADW|MEX_ES_00_P_Friv_IDE001_oo_oo_S_A;ADW;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000069be-2f9a-41a6-baae-730cd8780604;83.213.241.17;ES;100004945907632;0975b579655e757680311c2c6ec62b95;milanuncios.com;http://www.milanuncios.com/camiones-usados/camion-basculante-con-grua.htm?hasta=10000&demanda=n;eikkoifbpgbfhomedpfcahpnghoencio;80;ADW|MEX_ES_00_P_Friv_IDE001_oo_oo_S_A;ADW;;
>       29; 371
>       20160502;000069be-2f9a-41a6-baae-730cd8780604;83.213.241.17;ES;100004945907632;09ca50dda6debfc3010dcb4b1537e4c9;milanuncios.com;http://www.milanuncios.com/camiones-usados/scania-112.htm?hasta=10000&demanda=n;eikkoifbpgbfhomedpfcahpnghoencio;80;ADW|MEX_ES_00_P_Friv_IDE001_oo_oo_S_A;ADW;;
>       29; 371
>       20160502;000069be-2f9a-41a6-baae-730cd8780604;83.213.241.17;ES;100004945907632;1300ecd3136c73f81846351e70ce3abd;thenexttask.com;http://www.thenexttask.com/;eikkoifbpgbfhomedpfcahpnghoencio;80;ADW|MEX_ES_00_P_Friv_IDE001_oo_oo_S_A;ADW;;;
>       20160502;000069be-2f9a-41a6-baae-730cd8780604;83.213.241.17;ES;100004945907632;16d930b1791eaf15a989689ab9018d42;oi.bankia.es;https://oi.bankia.es/es/login/;eikkoifbpgbfhomedpfcahpnghoencio;80;ADW|MEX_ES_00_P_Friv_IDE001_oo_oo_S_A;ADW;;
>       13; 164
>       20160502;000069be-2f9a-41a6-baae-730cd8780604;83.213.241.17;ES;100004945907632;17b0cde478d82bc0cf19f71c5f7cd7c6;paisdelosjuegos.es;http://www.paisdelosjuegos.es/juego/dinosaurio/dinosaur+dash.html;eikkoifbpgbfhomedpfcahpnghoencio;80;ADW|MEX_ES_00_P_Friv_IDE001_oo_oo_S_A;ADW;;
>       28; 357
>       20160502;000069be-2f9a-41a6-baae-730cd8780604;83.213.241.17;ES;100004945907632;188c0ad2ed48b7cb60cdb5f4f7e16ae0;pinterest.com;https://www.pinterest.com/pin/435160382714835560/?from_navigate=true;eikkoifbpgbfhomedpfcahpnghoencio;80;ADW|MEX_ES_00_P_Friv_IDE001_oo_oo_S_A;ADW;;
>       31; 459
>       20160502;000069be-2f9a-41a6-baae-730cd8780604;83.213.241.17;ES;100004945907632;1a84b17addf5b35217cc7fc3e71b5e57;amazon.es;http://www.amazon.es/gp/bit/apps/web/SERP/search/ref=bit_bds-p23_serp_cr_es?query=que+tipo+de+musica+cantan+Maria+Callas+y+Luciano+Pavaroti&ie=UTF8&tbrId=v1_abb-channel-23_96a65e4ff4b94b7292ea204e971d4125_39_1006_20140524_ES_cr_ds_es79win-pd&ascsubtag=1ba_0_spk_000-os-device-browser-localeTest-testApp-custom%3AA%7Ccustom%3AB&tag=bds-p23-serp-es-cr-21&tagbase=bds-p23;eikkoifbpgbfhomedpfcahpnghoencio;80;ADW|MEX_ES_00_P_Friv_IDE001_oo_oo_S_A;ADW;;
>       29; 371
>       20160502;000069be-2f9a-41a6-baae-730cd8780604;83.213.241.17;ES;100004945907632;1b79921d00d221adfe81e6c6c8cbfff2;youtube.com;https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGy_w6hCL7E;eikkoifbpgbfhomedpfcahpnghoencio;80;ADW|MEX_ES_00_P_Friv_IDE001_oo_oo_S_A;ADW;;
>       10; 127
>       20160502;000069be-2f9a-41a6-baae-730cd8780604;83.213.241.17;ES;100004945907632;1b79921d00d221adfe81e6c6c8cbfff2;youtube.com;https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGy_w6hCL7E;eikkoifbpgbfhomedpfcahpnghoencio;80;ADW|MEX_ES_00_P_Friv_IDE001_oo_oo_S_A;ADW;;
>   10; 127

Aparentemente y a mi modo de ver, debería funcionar, pero no consigo que me imprima el resultado del `rdd`. Algo debo estar haciendo mal, pero no soy capaz de verlo... A ver si podéis echarme una mano.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: que error tienes?

Answer (score 0):

Los `rdd` son estructuras distribuidas. Creo que operaciones de entrada y salida no son tan triviales. Deberías tener los datos dentro de tu driver para poder imprimirlos, es decir:

```
rddSplit.collect.foreach(println)
```

Tienes que tener cuidado con este tipo de instrucciones porque te pueden **desbordar la memoria**.

Es muy diferente si escribes los resultados en un fichero. Esa forma debería ser más natural que imprimirlos.

Answer (score -1):

```fecha_local;idusuario;ip;pais_iso2;_F;idpageview;dominio;url;idextension;extension_version;source;partner;first;categoria;subcategoria 20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;009fe203badd9ef18ee5774183fcc1a6;sso.cmpc.com.mx;https://elite-autolavado.com/processJespa;oajabpccenjeimnmjcndiodkcndomfoh;80;ADSTRACT|{aff_id};ADSTRACT;;; 20160502;000064bd-ae88-4535-88bf-3352422799d0;207.248.58.83;MX;100009416501973;00e8c1d5a9b83d1d48c2be423d99b32a;facebook.com;https://www.facebook.com/````

Escribir los datos en un fichero seria mejor opcion

Comment: Que clase de respuesta es esta? No ayuda en nada ni proporciona ninguna informacion